# How to monitor hard drive thrashing with SSD?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

A question I just asked here regarding HDD hard drive thrashing has prompted me to give pause and think about SSD thrashing.  IMO, thrashing (ie, rapid and excessive reads and/or writes) is never good and should never be tolerated.  With HDDs, you know you're being thrashed because you can hear it, but what about silent SSDs with no moveable parts?

I can't help but wonder what sneaky tricks developers will hide in their applications once SSDs become more common (after the prices go down, for instance).  Applications will be able to access your drive virtually all they want because you'll never know it's happening.

Therefore, it only seems plausible that some sort of drive access monitoring tool would exist to let you know when you're being thrashed.  It could even prompt you and ask you to allow hard drive read/write permission whenever a particular process attempts to access your drive.  Does something like this already exist?

Comment: You can at least view the accesses in task managers such as process-hacker, but it will not notify you. And of course you can monitor the SSD self-reported wear level and see when it is reporting a health of less than 100%, but that is also a little too late.

Comment: Most desktops and laptops have a LED to indicate drive activity. If there is a lot of access it will light up. And as dontomaso wrote, you can use the resource manager. The long but easy way to styart that is Control-Alt-Del, start task manager, tab "performance", click on the icon at the bottom named "Resouce monitor". Use its "Disk" tab to see which applications are reading and writing to the disk.

Comment: The problem with monitoring it manually (ie, task manager, keeping an eye on the flashing LED, resource manager, etc) is that you have to know to check there in the first place, the crux of the problem with SSD since there's nothing grabbing your attention (when was the last time you stared at your drive's LED waiting for it to go into a blinking frenzy?).  So it looks like there's no way right now to monitor drive activity and receive alerts when excessive reads and writes are taking place.  I think that such applications will start to surface as SSDs become more widespread.